# C++ lambda function in priority_queue with capture by reference

Tags: algorithm, lambda, comparator, priority-queue

I was solving an algorithm problem - "find k-th ugly number", below is the problem statement and my implementation.

```
Write a program to find the n-th ugly number.
Ugly numbers are positive numbers whose prime factors only include 2, 3, 5. 
For example, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12 is the sequence of the first 10 ugly numbers.

vector<int> tmp(1,1);
vector<int> primes({2,3,5});
vector<int> indices(3, 0);
// lambda function pass in variables are captured by reference
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, function<bool(const int&, const int&)>> pq([&](const int& a, const int& b){
    return primes[a] * tmp[indices[a]] > primes[b] * tmp[indices[b]];
});
pq.push(0); pq.push(1); pq.push(2);
while(tmp.size() <= 3) { // find the first three ugly number
    int primeIndex = pq.top();
    pq.pop();
    int nextval = primes[primeIndex] * tmp[indices[primeIndex]];
    pq.push(primeIndex + 1);
    indices[primeIndex]++;

    while(!pq.empty() && primes[pq.top()] & tmp[indices[pq.top()]]) {
        primeIndex = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        pq.push(primeIndex + 1);
        indices[primeIndex]++;
    }
    cout << nextval << endl;
    tmp.push_back(nextval);
}
return 0;
```

the usage of priority_queue is an optimization for this solution. Priority_queue finds the "next ugly" number in O(logN) time. The priority_queue uses the index of primes[] as its elements. It uses a lambda function as the comparator and captures all outside variables **by reference**. I tested my code to output the first 3 ugly numbers (should be 2, 3, 4), but my code gave me "2, 6, 0". I think there is something wrong about my lambda function in the priority_queue, but I could not find out why. Could anyone give me a hint on resolving my bug? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem with your code is that you are accessing the `tmp` vector out of bounds. You use elements of `indices` as indices into `tmp`, and you increment the elements of `indices` in multiple places within the iteration of the outer while loop (once before the inner while loop, and potentially one or more times within the inner while loop), and you only increase the size of `tmp` at the end of the iteration of the outer while loop. In the meantime, in the condition of the inner while loop, you index `tmp` with the indices that you may have increased (potentially multiple times) before you get to increasing the size of `tmp`.